# corrplot parameters in R

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I have used the corrplot as below, but as you can see I need to enlarge the font size of numbers inside the circles and then the plot title is not in a correct position and font size(not visible completely) but I can not find the parameters for them. I will be grateful if you could help.

```
library(corrplot)

png(height=1200, width=1200, file="overlap.png")

col1 <-rainbow(100, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = 0.9, alpha = 1)
test <- matrix(data=c(20:60),nrow=7,ncol=7)

corrplot(test,tl.cex=3,title="Overlaps Between methods",
  method="circle",is.corr=FALSE,type="full",
  cl.lim=c(10,100),cl.cex=2,addgrid.col="red",
  addshade="positive",col=col1, diag=FALSE,
  addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0, alpha = 0.6)
)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: @Arun, now I think it is reproducible. I need to change the font size of texts inside the circles. But maybe they are proportional to some other parameters.

Comment: on my `Rstudio`, it prints perfectly fine! The problem seems to be with the `height=` and `width=` parameter in `png`. IF you remove it, it gives good results. Even better is with `pdf("myfile.pdf")`.

Comment: @Arun even the title? did you use the png and dev.off as well?

Comment: check the answer. I think this is what you were looking for..?

Comment: For anyone trying to do something similar, cl.lim is now col.lim after version 0.9.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `png()` with the `height=1200` and `width=1200` options you provide. Try changing that line to:

```
png(height=1200, width=1200, pointsize=25, file="overlap.png")
```

The default `pointsize = 12` somehow reduces the fonts of the `labels` and `title`, for some reason.

**Edit:** To see the title properly add this parameter to your `corrplot`:

```
mar=c(0,0,1,0)
```

So the entire command set is:

```
library(corrplot)
png(height=1200, width=1200, pointsize=25, file="overlap.png")
col1 <-rainbow(100, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = 0.9, alpha = 1)
test <- matrix(data=c(20:60),nrow=7,ncol=7)
corrplot(test,tl.cex=3,title="Overlaps Between methods",
method="circle",is.corr=FALSE,type="full",
cl.lim=c(10,100),cl.cex=2,addgrid.col=
"red",addshade="positive",col=col1, addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0, alpha =
0.6), mar=c(0,0,1,0), diag= FALSE) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: in 2021, pasting the code chunk into R no longer seems to work. The error is `null device`

Answer (score 1):

Rename parameter cl.lim to col.lim in corrplot()
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/news/news.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).