# How to change font size of the correlation coefficient in corrplot?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I am plotting correlation plot with corrplot. I want to plot also the correlation coefficients:

```
require(corrplot)
test <- matrix(data = rnorm(400), nrow=20, ncol=20)
corrplot(cor(test), method = "color", addCoef.col="grey", order = "AOE")
```

But they are too big in the plot:

[image]

Is there any way to make the font of the coefficent smaller? I've been looking at `?corrplot` but there are only parameters to change the legend and axis font sizes (`cl.cex` and `tl.cex`). `pch.cex` doesn't work either.

Comment: As a quick fix you could set `par(cex=0.4)` and then add `tl.cex` , `cl.cex` arguments

Comment: @user20650, I tried to use `cex` parameter to the corrplot, it throwed an error, but this works! It is a bit dirty though.. as you have to reset it back by `par(cex = 1)` afterwards for other plots...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is far from the answer, it is kind of a dirty hack, but this works (thanks  user20650 for the idea):

```
cex.before <- par("cex")
par(cex = 0.7)
corrplot(cor(envV), p.mat = cor1[[1]], insig = "blank", method = "color",
    addCoef.col="grey", 
    order = "AOE", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"),
    cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
par(cex = cex.before)
```

Comment: I think is a nice solution!

Answer (score 39):

The option to use is `number.cex=`.
As in the following:

```
corrplot(cor(test),
   method = "color", 
   addCoef.col="grey", 
   order = "AOE", 
   number.cex=0.75)
```

To make it dynamic, try `number.cex= 7/ncol(df)` where `df` is dataframe for which the correlation was run.

Comment: @invictus, sorry to hear that. If you could share the non-working code, I could try and solve it.

Comment: this works great, also try tl.cex = .7 as well to change font size of the group label.

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same problem a little while ago when I had to do a corrplot similar to yours. After a lot of searching I found a solution which involves printing the correlation plot to a png file and altering the parameters there.

i.e.:

```
library(corrplot)
test <- matrix(data = rnorm(400), nrow=20, ncol=20)
png(height=1200, width=1500, pointsize=15, file="overlap.png")
corrplot(cor(test), method = "color", addCoef.col="grey", order = "AOE")
```

The part that increases/decreases the font inside the cells is parameter pointsize. setting it to 15 you can see that the numbers now fit the cells.

[image: correlation plot]

You may also find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753344/corrplot-parameters-in-r) helpful. it certainly helped me.

Comment: Dear LyzandeR, thanks! I've saw your question before asking, but png export didn't satisfy me. The `par(cex)` is little less dirty trick (but still dirty). Anyway, as you are already corrplot-experienced, would you know answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26574670/684229 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would define my own size value since the function just ommited allowing for a size to be added to that text. Below is the function recreated with an extra number.cex paramater added at the end, which controls the number label size now.

```
corrplot2 <- function (corr, method = c("circle", "square", "ellipse", "number", 
                                        "shade", "color", "pie"), type = c("full", "lower", "upper"), 
                       add = FALSE, col = NULL, bg = "white", title = "", is.corr = TRUE, 
                       diag = TRUE, outline = FALSE, mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), addgrid.col = NULL, 
                       addCoef.col = NULL, addCoefasPercent = FALSE, order = c("original", 
                                                                               "AOE", "FPC", "hclust", "alphabet"), hclust.method = c("complete", 
                                                                                                                                      "ward", "single", "average", "mcquitty", "median", "centroid"), 
                       addrect = NULL, rect.col = "black", rect.lwd = 2, tl.pos = NULL, 
                       tl.cex = 1, tl.col = "red", tl.offset = 0.4, tl.srt = 90, 
                       cl.pos = NULL, cl.lim = NULL, cl.length = NULL, cl.cex = 0.8, 
                       cl.ratio = 0.15, cl.align.text = "c", cl.offset = 0.5, addshade = c("negative", 
                                                                                           "positive", "all"), shade.lwd = 1, shade.col = "white", 
                       p.mat = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, insig = c("pch", "p-value", 
                                                                 "blank", "n"), pch = 4, pch.col = "black", pch.cex = 3, 
                       plotCI = c("n", "square", "circle", "rect"), lowCI.mat = NULL, 
                       uppCI.mat = NULL, number.cex = 0.7, ...) 
{
  method <- match.arg(method)
  type <- match.arg(type)
  order <- match.arg(order)
  hclust.method <- match.arg(hclust.method)
  plotCI <- match.arg(plotCI)
  insig <- match.arg(insig)
  if (!is.matrix(corr) & !is.data.frame(corr)) 
    stop("Need a matrix or data frame!")
  if (is.null(addgrid.col)) {
    addgrid.col <- ifelse(method == "color" | method == "shade", 
                          "white", "grey")
  }
  if (any(corr < cl.lim[1]) | any(corr > cl.lim[2])) 
    stop("color limits should cover matrix")
  if (is.null(cl.lim)) {
    if (is.corr) 
      cl.lim <- c(-1, 1)
    if (!is.corr) 
      cl.lim <- c(min(corr), max(corr))
  }
  intercept <- 0
  zoom <- 1
  if (!is.corr) {
    if (max(corr) * min(corr) < 0) {
      intercept <- 0
      zoom <- 1/max(abs(cl.lim))
    }
    if (min(corr) >= 0) {
      intercept <- -cl.lim[1]
      zoom <- 1/(diff(cl.lim))
    }
    if (max(corr) <= 0) {
      intercept <- -cl.lim[2]
      zoom <- 1/(diff(cl.lim))
    }
    corr <- (intercept + corr) * zoom
  }
  cl.lim2 <- (intercept + cl.lim) * zoom
  int <- intercept * zoom
  if (min(corr) < -1 - .Machine$double.eps || max(corr) > 1 + 
      .Machine$double.eps) {
    stop("The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!")
  }
  if (is.null(col)) {
    col <- colorRampPalette(c("#67001F", "#B2182B", "#D6604D", 
                              "#F4A582", "#FDDBC7", "#FFFFFF", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE", 
                              "#4393C3", "#2166AC", "#053061"))(200)
  }
  n <- nrow(corr)
  m <- ncol(corr)
  min.nm <- min(n, m)
  ord <- 1:min.nm
  if (!order == "original") {
    ord <- corrMatOrder(corr, order = order, hclust.method = hclust.method)
    corr <- corr[ord, ord]
  }
  if (is.null(rownames(corr))) 
    rownames(corr) <- 1:n
  if (is.null(colnames(corr))) 
    colnames(corr) <- 1:m
  getPos.Dat <- function(mat) {
    x <- matrix(1:n * m, n, m)
    tmp <- mat
    if (type == "upper") 
      tmp[row(x) > col(x)] <- Inf
    if (type == "lower") 
      tmp[row(x) < col(x)] <- Inf
    if (type == "full") 
      tmp <- tmp
    if (!diag) 
      diag(tmp) <- Inf
    Dat <- tmp[is.finite(tmp)]
    ind <- which(is.finite(tmp), arr.ind = TRUE)
    Pos <- ind
    Pos[, 1] <- ind[, 2]
    Pos[, 2] <- -ind[, 1] + 1 + n
    return(list(Pos, Dat))
  }
  Pos <- getPos.Dat(corr)[[1]]
  n2 <- max(Pos[, 2])
  n1 <- min(Pos[, 2])
  nn <- n2 - n1
  newrownames <- as.character(rownames(corr)[(n + 1 - n2):(n + 
                                                             1 - n1)])
  m2 <- max(Pos[, 1])
  m1 <- min(Pos[, 1])
  mm <- m2 - m1
  newcolnames <- as.character(colnames(corr)[m1:m2])
  DAT <- getPos.Dat(corr)[[2]]
  len.DAT <- length(DAT)
  assign.color <- function(DAT) {
    newcorr <- (DAT + 1)/2
    newcorr[newcorr == 1] <- 1 - 0.0000000001
    col.fill <- col[floor(newcorr * length(col)) + 1]
  }
  col.fill <- assign.color(DAT)
  isFALSE = function(x) identical(x, FALSE)
  isTRUE = function(x) identical(x, TRUE)
  if (isFALSE(tl.pos)) {
    tl.pos <- "n"
  }
  if (is.null(tl.pos) | isTRUE(tl.pos)) {
    if (type == "full") 
      tl.pos <- "lt"
    if (type == "lower") 
      tl.pos <- "ld"
    if (type == "upper") 
      tl.pos <- "td"
  }
  if (isFALSE(cl.pos)) {
    cl.pos <- "n"
  }
  if (is.null(cl.pos) | isTRUE(cl.pos)) {
    if (type == "full") 
      cl.pos <- "r"
    if (type == "lower") 
      cl.pos <- "b"
    if (type == "upper") 
      cl.pos <- "r"
  }
  if (outline) 
    col.border <- "black"
  if (!outline) 
    col.border <- col.fill
  if (!add) {
    par(mar = mar, bg = "white")
    plot.new()
    xlabwidth <- ylabwidth <- 0
    for (i in 1:50) {
      xlim <- c(m1 - 0.5 - xlabwidth, m2 + 0.5 + mm * cl.ratio * 
                  (cl.pos == "r"))
      ylim <- c(n1 - 0.5 - nn * cl.ratio * (cl.pos == "b"), 
                n2 + 0.5 + ylabwidth)
      plot.window(xlim + c(-0.2, 0.2), ylim + c(-0.2, 0.2), 
                  asp = 1, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
      x.tmp <- max(strwidth(newrownames, cex = tl.cex))
      y.tmp <- max(strwidth(newcolnames, cex = tl.cex))
      if (min(x.tmp - xlabwidth, y.tmp - ylabwidth) < 0.0001) 
        break
      xlabwidth <- x.tmp
      ylabwidth <- y.tmp
    }
    if (tl.pos == "n" | tl.pos == "d") 
      xlabwidth <- ylabwidth <- 0
    if (tl.pos == "td") 
      ylabwidth <- 0
    if (tl.pos == "ld") 
      xlabwidth <- 0
    laboffset <- strwidth("W", cex = tl.cex) * tl.offset
    xlim <- c(m1 - 0.5 - xlabwidth - laboffset, m2 + 0.5 + 
                mm * cl.ratio * (cl.pos == "r")) + c(-0.35, 0.15)
    ylim <- c(n1 - 0.5 - nn * cl.ratio * (cl.pos == "b"), 
              n2 + 0.5 + ylabwidth * abs(sin(tl.srt * pi/180)) + 
                laboffset) + c(-0.15, 0.35)
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
      windows.options(width = 7, height = 7 * diff(ylim)/diff(xlim))
    }
    plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, asp = 1, xlab = "", 
                ylab = "", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
  }
  laboffset <- strwidth("W", cex = tl.cex) * tl.offset
  symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, squares = rep(1, 
                                                         len.DAT), bg = bg, fg = bg)
  if (method == "circle" & plotCI == "n") {
    symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, bg = col.fill, 
            circles = 0.9 * abs(DAT)^0.5/2, fg = col.border)
  }
  if (method == "ellipse" & plotCI == "n") {
    ell.dat <- function(rho, length = 99) {
      k <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = length)
      x <- cos(k + acos(rho)/2)/2
      y <- cos(k - acos(rho)/2)/2
      return(cbind(rbind(x, y), c(NA, NA)))
    }
    ELL.dat <- lapply(DAT, ell.dat)
    ELL.dat2 <- 0.85 * matrix(unlist(ELL.dat), ncol = 2, 
                              byrow = TRUE)
    ELL.dat2 <- ELL.dat2 + Pos[rep(1:length(DAT), each = 100), 
                               ]
    polygon(ELL.dat2, border = col.border, col = col.fill)
  }
  if (method == "number" & plotCI == "n") {
    text(Pos[, 1], Pos[, 2], font = 2, col = col.fill, labels = round((DAT - 
                                                                         int) * ifelse(addCoefasPercent, 100, 1)/zoom, ifelse(addCoefasPercent, 
                                                                                                                              0, 2)))
  }
  if (method == "pie" & plotCI == "n") {
    symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, circles = rep(0.5, 
                                                           len.DAT) * 0.85)
    pie.dat <- function(theta, length = 100) {
      k <- seq(pi/2, pi/2 - theta, length = 0.5 * length * 
                 abs(theta)/pi)
      x <- c(0, cos(k)/2, 0)
      y <- c(0, sin(k)/2, 0)
      return(cbind(rbind(x, y), c(NA, NA)))
    }
    PIE.dat <- lapply(DAT * 2 * pi, pie.dat)
    len.pie <- unlist(lapply(PIE.dat, length))/2
    PIE.dat2 <- 0.85 * matrix(unlist(PIE.dat), ncol = 2, 
                              byrow = TRUE)
    PIE.dat2 <- PIE.dat2 + Pos[rep(1:length(DAT), len.pie), 
                               ]
    polygon(PIE.dat2, border = "black", col = col.fill)
  }
  if (method == "shade" & plotCI == "n") {
    addshade <- match.arg(addshade)
    symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, squares = rep(1, 
                                                           len.DAT), bg = col.fill, fg = addgrid.col)
    shade.dat <- function(w) {
      x <- w[1]
      y <- w[2]
      rho <- w[3]
      x1 <- x - 0.5
      x2 <- x + 0.5
      y1 <- y - 0.5
      y2 <- y + 0.5
      dat <- NA
      if ((addshade == "positive" || addshade == "all") & 
          rho > 0) {
        dat <- cbind(c(x1, x1, x), c(y, y1, y1), c(x, 
                                                   x2, x2), c(y2, y2, y))
      }
      if ((addshade == "negative" || addshade == "all") & 
          rho < 0) {
        dat <- cbind(c(x1, x1, x), c(y, y2, y2), c(x, 
                                                   x2, x2), c(y1, y1, y))
      }
      return(t(dat))
    }
    pos_corr <- rbind(cbind(Pos, DAT))
    pos_corr2 <- split(pos_corr, 1:nrow(pos_corr))
    SHADE.dat <- matrix(na.omit(unlist(lapply(pos_corr2, 
                                              shade.dat))), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 4)
    segments(SHADE.dat[, 1], SHADE.dat[, 2], SHADE.dat[, 
                                                       3], SHADE.dat[, 4], col = shade.col, lwd = shade.lwd)
  }
  if (method == "square" & plotCI == "n") {
    symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, squares = abs(DAT)^0.5, 
            bg = col.fill, fg = col.border)
  }
  if (method == "color" & plotCI == "n") {
    symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, squares = rep(1, 
                                                           len.DAT), bg = col.fill, fg = col.border)
  }
  symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, bg = NA, squares = rep(1, 
                                                                  len.DAT), fg = addgrid.col)
  if (plotCI != "n") {
    if (is.null(lowCI.mat) || is.null(uppCI.mat)) 
      stop("Need lowCI.mat and uppCI.mat!")
    if (!order == "original") {
      lowCI.mat <- lowCI.mat[ord, ord]
      uppCI.mat <- uppCI.mat[ord, ord]
    }
    pos.lowNew <- getPos.Dat(lowCI.mat)[[1]]
    lowNew <- getPos.Dat(lowCI.mat)[[2]]
    pos.uppNew <- getPos.Dat(uppCI.mat)[[1]]
    uppNew <- getPos.Dat(uppCI.mat)[[2]]
    if (!(method == "circle" || method == "square")) 
      stop("method shoud be circle or square if draw confidence interval!")
    k1 <- (abs(uppNew) > abs(lowNew))
    bigabs <- uppNew
    bigabs[which(!k1)] <- lowNew[!k1]
    smallabs <- lowNew
    smallabs[which(!k1)] <- uppNew[!k1]
    sig <- sign(uppNew * lowNew)
    if (plotCI == "circle") {
      symbols(pos.uppNew[, 1], pos.uppNew[, 2], add = TRUE, 
              inches = FALSE, circles = 0.95 * abs(bigabs)^0.5/2, 
              bg = ifelse(sig > 0, col.fill, col[ceiling((bigabs + 
                                                            1) * length(col)/2)]), fg = ifelse(sig > 0, 
                                                                                               col.fill, col[ceiling((bigabs + 1) * length(col)/2)]))
      symbols(pos.lowNew[, 1], pos.lowNew[, 2], add = TRUE, 
              inches = FALSE, circles = 0.95 * abs(smallabs)^0.5/2, 
              bg = ifelse(sig > 0, bg, col[ceiling((smallabs + 
                                                      1) * length(col)/2)]), fg = ifelse(sig > 0, 
                                                                                         col.fill, col[ceiling((smallabs + 1) * length(col)/2)]))
    }
    if (plotCI == "square") {
      symbols(pos.uppNew[, 1], pos.uppNew[, 2], add = TRUE, 
              inches = FALSE, squares = abs(bigabs)^0.5, bg = ifelse(sig > 
                                                                       0, col.fill, col[ceiling((bigabs + 1) * length(col)/2)]), 
              fg = ifelse(sig > 0, col.fill, col[ceiling((bigabs + 
                                                            1) * length(col)/2)]))
      symbols(pos.lowNew[, 1], pos.lowNew[, 2], add = TRUE, 
              inches = FALSE, squares = abs(smallabs)^0.5, 
              bg = ifelse(sig > 0, bg, col[ceiling((smallabs + 
                                                      1) * length(col)/2)]), fg = ifelse(sig > 0, 
                                                                                         col.fill, col[ceiling((smallabs + 1) * length(col)/2)]))
    }
    if (plotCI == "rect") {
      rect.width <- 0.25
      rect(pos.uppNew[, 1] - rect.width, pos.uppNew[, 2] + 
             smallabs/2, pos.uppNew[, 1] + rect.width, pos.uppNew[, 
                                                                  2] + bigabs/2, col = col.fill, border = col.fill)
      segments(pos.lowNew[, 1] - rect.width, pos.lowNew[, 
                                                        2] + DAT/2, pos.lowNew[, 1] + rect.width, pos.lowNew[, 
                                                                                                             2] + DAT/2, col = "black", lwd = 1)
      segments(pos.uppNew[, 1] - rect.width, pos.uppNew[, 
                                                        2] + uppNew/2, pos.uppNew[, 1] + rect.width, 
               pos.uppNew[, 2] + uppNew/2, col = "black", lwd = 1)
      segments(pos.lowNew[, 1] - rect.width, pos.lowNew[, 
                                                        2] + lowNew/2, pos.lowNew[, 1] + rect.width, 
               pos.lowNew[, 2] + lowNew/2, col = "black", lwd = 1)
      segments(pos.lowNew[, 1] - 0.5, pos.lowNew[, 2], 
               pos.lowNew[, 1] + 0.5, pos.lowNew[, 2], col = "grey70", 
               lty = 3)
    }
  }
  if (!is.null(p.mat) & !insig == "n") {
    if (!order == "original") 
      p.mat <- p.mat[ord, ord]
    pos.pNew <- getPos.Dat(p.mat)[[1]]
    pNew <- getPos.Dat(p.mat)[[2]]
    ind.p <- which(pNew > (sig.level))
    if (insig == "pch") {
      points(pos.pNew[, 1][ind.p], pos.pNew[, 2][ind.p], 
             pch = pch, col = pch.col, cex = pch.cex, lwd = 2)
    }
    if (insig == "p-value") {
      text(pos.pNew[, 1][ind.p], pos.pNew[, 2][ind.p], 
           round(pNew[ind.p], 2), col = pch.col)
    }
    if (insig == "blank") {
      symbols(pos.pNew[, 1][ind.p], pos.pNew[, 2][ind.p], 
              inches = FALSE, squares = rep(1, length(pos.pNew[, 
                                                               1][ind.p])), fg = addgrid.col, bg = bg, add = TRUE)
    }
  }
  if (cl.pos != "n") {
    colRange <- assign.color(cl.lim2)
    ind1 <- which(col == colRange[1])
    ind2 <- which(col == colRange[2])
    colbar <- col[ind1:ind2]
    if (is.null(cl.length)) 
      cl.length <- ifelse(length(colbar) > 20, 11, length(colbar) + 
                            1)
    labels <- seq(cl.lim[1], cl.lim[2], length = cl.length)
    at <- seq(0, 1, length = length(labels))
    if (cl.pos == "r") {
      vertical <- TRUE
      xlim <- c(m2 + 0.5 + mm * 0.02, m2 + 0.5 + mm * cl.ratio)
      ylim <- c(n1 - 0.5, n2 + 0.5)
    }
    if (cl.pos == "b") {
      vertical <- FALSE
      xlim <- c(m1 - 0.5, m2 + 0.5)
      ylim <- c(n1 - 0.5 - nn * cl.ratio, n1 - 0.5 - nn * 
                  0.02)
    }
    colorlegend(colbar = colbar, labels = round(labels, 2), 
                offset = cl.offset, ratio.colbar = 0.3, cex = cl.cex, 
                xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, vertical = vertical, align = cl.align.text)
  }
  if (tl.pos != "n") {
    ylabwidth2 <- strwidth(newrownames, cex = tl.cex)
    xlabwidth2 <- strwidth(newcolnames, cex = tl.cex)
    pos.xlabel <- cbind(m1:m2, n2 + 0.5 + laboffset)
    pos.ylabel <- cbind(m1 - 0.5, n2:n1)
    if (tl.pos == "td") {
      if (type != "upper") 
        stop("type should be \"upper\" if tl.pos is \"dt\".")
      pos.ylabel <- cbind(m1:(m1 + nn) - 0.5, n2:n1)
    }
    if (tl.pos == "ld") {
      if (type != "lower") 
        stop("type should be \"lower\" if tl.pos is \"ld\".")
      pos.xlabel <- cbind(m1:m2, n2:(n2 - mm) + 0.5 + laboffset)
    }
    if (tl.pos == "d") {
      pos.ylabel <- cbind(m1:(m1 + nn) - 0.5, n2:n1)
      pos.ylabel <- pos.ylabel[1:min(n, m), ]
      symbols(pos.ylabel[, 1] + 0.5, pos.ylabel[, 2], add = TRUE, 
              bg = bg, fg = addgrid.col, inches = FALSE, squares = rep(1, 
                                                                       length(pos.ylabel[, 1])))
      text(pos.ylabel[, 1] + 0.5, pos.ylabel[, 2], newcolnames[1:min(n, 
                                                                     m)], col = tl.col, cex = tl.cex, ...)
    }
    else {
      text(pos.xlabel[, 1], pos.xlabel[, 2], newcolnames, 
           srt = tl.srt, adj = ifelse(tl.srt == 0, c(0.5, 
                                                     0), c(0, 0)), col = tl.col, cex = tl.cex, offset = tl.offset, 
           ...)
      text(pos.ylabel[, 1], pos.ylabel[, 2], newrownames, 
           col = tl.col, cex = tl.cex, pos = 2, offset = tl.offset, 
           ...)
    }
  }
  title(title, ...)
  if (!is.null(addCoef.col) & (!method == "number")) {
    text(Pos[, 1], Pos[, 2], col = addCoef.col, labels = round((DAT - 
                                                                  int) * ifelse(addCoefasPercent, 100, 1)/zoom, ifelse(addCoefasPercent, 
                                                                                                                       0, 2)), cex = number.cex)
  }
  if (type == "full" & plotCI == "n" & !is.null(addgrid.col)) 
    rect(m1 - 0.5, n1 - 0.5, m2 + 0.5, n2 + 0.5, border = addgrid.col)
  if (!is.null(addrect) & order == "hclust" & type == "full") {
    corrRect.hclust(corr, k = addrect, method = hclust.method, 
                    col = rect.col, lwd = rect.lwd)
  }
  invisible(corr)
}
```