# corrplot shows insignificant correlation coefficients even when insig = "blank" is set

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I like to use correlation plot using `corrplot` function with correlation coefficients printed in the cells (using `addCoef.col` and `addCoefasPercent = TRUE`). I also like to remove the insignificant correlations from the plot (using `insig = "blank"`). The problem is that this only works for the background color, but not for the coefficient itself, so the coefficient itself is still printed! See:

```
set.seed(123)
par(cex=0.8) # trick for cor. coef font size, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26574054/684229
col1 <-rainbow(100, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = 0.9, alpha = 1)
test <- matrix(data=rnorm(400),nrow=20,ncol=20)


cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95){
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for(i in 1:(n-1)){
        for(j in (i+1):n){
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
            lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
            uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
        }
    }
    return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}

cor1 <- cor.mtest(test, 0.95)

corrplot(cor(test), p.mat = cor1[[1]], insig = "blank", method = "color", addCoef.col="grey", 
    order = "AOE", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"),
    cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
```

Now you can see that the coefficients are printed also for the insignificant cells:

[image]

Just to see which cells are insignificant, you can use this command:

```
corrplot(cor(test), p.mat = cor1[[1]], insig = "pch", method = "color", addCoef.col="grey", 
    order = "AOE", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"),
    cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
```

Perhaps this is a bug of corrplot package?

**How can I get rid of printing the coefficient in insignificant cells?**

Comment: You could start by putting a library call to load the package with the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to do a little work for this. You need to define a vector of colours manually for the p-values, that is passed to `addCoef.col`

If you were ordering alphabetically, it is straight forward

```
mycol <- ifelse(c(cor1[[1]] < 0.05), "black", "white")

corrplot(cor(test), p.mat = cor1[[1]] , insig = "blank", method = "color", 
         addCoef.col=mycol ,
         order = "original", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"), 
         cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
```

But as you want to order by the eigenvalues you need to calculate the ordering outside of the `corrplot` function

```
ord <-   corrMatOrder(cor(test), order="AOE")
M <- cor(test)[ord, ord]

pval <- psych::corr.test(data.frame(test), adjust="none")$p[ord, ord]
mycol <- ifelse(c(pval < 0.05), "black", "white")


corrplot(M, p.mat = pval , insig = "blank", method = "color", addCoef.col=mycol ,
         order = "original", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"), 
         cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** re @Masi's comments

To update the limits on the colourbar set the limits with `cl.lim`

```
 corrplot(cor(test), p.mat = cor1[[1]] , insig = "blank", method = "color", 
       addCoef.col=mycol , addCoefasPercent=TRUE, 
       order = "original", cl.lim = c(-100, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! It is very stupid that in case of `order="AOE"` the order must be calculated outside of the corrplot function, as you mention! This is a flaw of the `corrplot` function. The `addCoef.col` should take a matrix that would be of the same order & format as the correlation matrix.

Comment: I found a better method! Just do `cl.lim=c(-100,100)`, it automatically scales the matrix values to [-100, 100], so you do not need to multiply anything and not even change the colourbar, just use the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too picky, you could also leave the background set to white and make your `addCoef.col = "white"` instead of `"grey"` as you have it originally.  That would eliminate the need for the ordering and ifelse statements.