# order of labels in corrplot after hclust

Tags: r, r-corrplot

In my dataset, variables belong to different groups and I want to assign the color for each variable:

```
mycolors <- rep(NA,11)
names(mycolors) <- names(mtcars)
mycolors[1:4]   <- 'green' # mpg, cyl, disp, hp
mycolors[5:9]   <- 'red'   # drat, wt, qsec, vs, am
mycolors[10:11] <- 'blue'  # gear, carb
```

Now I want to build a correlation matrix and color the labels:

```
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, tl.col = mycolors)
```

[image: no order]

This works fine, but if I order it with `hclust`, labels go in different order which makes colors wrong:
[image]

How to get the actual order of the labels after `hclust`, so that I can re-assign colors? I tried to use the following:

```
myclust <- hclust(dist(M))
myclust$labels[myclust$order]
```

this gives the order different from the original one, but still not the same as the order used in corrplot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574670/corrplot-shows-insignificant-correlation-coefficients-even-when-insig-blank/26575385#26575385) you can reorder your colour vector, so that it meets the order of the `hclust` ordered matrix.

```
ord <- corrMatOrder(M, order="hclust")
newcolours <- mycolors[ord]
newcolours
#   carb      wt      hp     cyl    disp    qsec      vs     mpg    drat      am 
# "blue"   "red" "green" "green" "green"   "red"   "red" "green"   "red"   "red" 
#   gear 
# "blue" 
corrplot(M, tl.col = newcolours, order = "hclust")
```