# Is it possible to make an asymmetric coloured correlation matrix plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, correlation, hmisc

I'd like to make a colored asymmetric correlation matrix in R. Essentially, it'll be a 4 by 6 correlation matrix (that looks something like the plots [here](https://www.displayr.com/how-to-create-a-correlation-matrix-in-r/)). I have simulated some data here as an example data set:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col2 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col3 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col4 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col5 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col6 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col7 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col8 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col9 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col10 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I want a coloured correlation plot that correlates `col1` to `col4` with `col5` to `col10`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Correlation matrices are quadratic by definition, so there is no way to create an "asymmetric correlation matrix". Please clarify what your goal is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `matrix` of the columns you want to `cor`. Maybe you want something like this:

```
dat.cor = cor(dat[,c(1,4)], dat[,5:10])

library(corrplot)
corrplot(as.matrix(dat.cor))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to leave out the correlations that are statistically insignificant?

Comment: @jo_, Yes that is possible. I would suggest having a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574670/corrplot-shows-insignificant-correlation-coefficients-even-when-insig-blank