# Font size of p-values in a significance corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Can anyone advise please:

I am using corrplot to obtain p-values for variables. 
number.cex= does not alter the font size of the p-values. 
Presently, I have a corrplot with outsize (unreadable) p-values, given that I have a relatively large number of variables (n = 27).

I've not been able to find any information on this via Rseek or Stack Overflow...

The below code was taken from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html).

There is some overly complicated-looking code [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram) that I could not get on with. Below is the code I'm using:

```
corrplot(HG_lipid_matrix, p.mat = res1$p, insig = "p-value", 
         sig.level = .05, number.cex = 0.2)
```

Altering the value of number.cex results in no change to the font size of p-values.

Many thanks :-)

Comment: Help for function says use pch.cex to do this.

Comment: Thanks - will give this a try :-)

Comment: Tried this and nope. pch.cex can only be used when insig = "pch" which only adds a cross where there is no significant coefficient.

Comment: The code I'm using is: corrplot(HG_lipid_matrix, p.mat = res1$p, insig = "p-value", sig.level = -1) As I say, the p-values are there, but the font size is just too big to read them.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/master/R/corrplot.R#L891) for `corrplot`, it doesn't appear to be an argument for adjusting the p-value cex. You could use `text()` after generating the plot to add your own p-values.

Comment: @henrik_ibsen How would you obtain the x and y coordinates for adding the labels manually with ```text()```   There was a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574054/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-correlation-coefficient-in-corrplot  Might give someone an idea of how to create a similar workaround for controlling p-value label size

Comment: For most cases, given the cormatrix `mat`, you have the coordinates `x=rep(1:nrow(mat), each=nrow(mat))` and  `y=rep(nrow(mat):1, nrow(mat))`. Then set order of the labels according to the order argument in `corrplot` using `corrplot::corrMatOrder` if `order != "original"`

Answer (score 0):

This plots the correlations of variables in `mtcars`, but this should work for you.
You can adjust the `mag.factor` and `par(cex = 0.7)` to suit your needs:

```
library(corrplot) #read-in corrplot package
M <- cor(mtcars) #obtain matrix of correlation coefficients (r values)
mag.factor <- 2 #fudge factor to increase size of axis (tl.cex) and legend (cl.tex) text relative to p-value text
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .95) #obtain matrix of correlation p-values
cex.before <- par("cex") #saves current cex setting for plotting
par(cex = 0.7)  #set cex for plotting text.  this invisibly affects p-value text.
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1$p, insig = "p-value", sig.level = -1, tl.cex = par("cex") * mag.factor, cl.cex = par("cex") * mag.factor) #makes the plot
par(cex = cex.before) #reset cex to initial setting
```

It was modified from an answer to a similar problem here: [How to change font size of the correlation coefficient in corrplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574054/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-correlation-coefficient-in-corrplot)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this code. It seems to work perfectly - very grateful for this. I am a relative newcomer to R and it would be a very big help to me if you have a moment to use the # symbol to explain what you've done in each step of the above code please! I have one very small issue: one of the p-values produced using this code is 0.03. However, when I run a basic linear model and use summary(), the p-value is slightly different - 0.02 (though of course, still significant). Do you have any idea why this might be the case please? Thank you again - this is a real lifer-saver!

Comment: Also, I needed to change par (cex = 0.7) to par (cex = 0.5) given that the font size of the p-values was still slightly large (I have a reasonable number of variables - 27).

Comment: Another small point (forgive me): The colours generated on the plot only sometimes equate with a significant p-value. It isn't clear what the colours are being influenced by. Is this somehow an artefact of the corrplot code colouring only where there is a high / low r-squared value? Thanks

Comment: @Mike_989, see commented code above.  The colors generated match the correlation coefficients (r, not r-squared), which is what the legend refers to on the right side of plot.  The colors don't refer to p-values.  r = 1 is a perfect positive correlation.  r = -1 is a perfect negative correlation.  P-values refer to the probability that the correlation strength could happen by chance, given the sample size.  So, low p-values will be associated with stronger correlations (bigger absolute r values, which could be either negative or positive).

Comment: Thanks again for all your help with this. I'm intrigued as to why this corrplot produces very slightly different p-values for some significant correlations compared to when I run a basic linear model and the summary () call for individual dependent and independent variables. This has been a great help. Becoming a big fan of Stack Overflow!

Comment: It may be rounding for plotting purposes.  I compared ```summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars))$r.squared``` and ```cor(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$mpg)^2``` and get same r-squared: 0.7262 .  Same p-value also from this ```cor.mtest(mtcars[,c('mpg', 'cyl')])```: 6.113e-10.

Comment: continuing from above: But this shows up as "0" in the plot.

Comment: Yep. I've had one or two anomalies like this - showing 0 in the plot when there is in fact a significant correlation. Bit of a worry. Would appreciate any advice as to how this might be remedied please.

Comment: The 0 indicates a very small p-value that was rounded down.  It does indicate significance.

Comment: Right - I see! Thanks very much indeed for all your help and advice with this. This has been a tremendous help to me! All the best, Mike.