# How to corrplot a single vector to other vectors?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I'd like to have a corrplot between a single vector and other several vectors. More simply, I would like to retrieve the first row of a classic corrplot matrix.
I use corr() function and corrplot() function, but It's only work with matrix.
Any idea for doing this? thank you very much

Comment: If `x` is a vector and `y` is a data frame of several vectors, then `corrplot(cor(x, y))` would work.

Comment: Well it doesn't work and I dont know why. I've got this message :   <br/>
'Error in symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, rectangles = matrix(1, : 
  coordinates of the symbols are incorrect
Also: Warning messages:
1: In min(corr, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no argument found for min; Inf is returned
2: In max(corr, na.rm = TRUE) : no argument for max ; -Inf is returned'   <br/>

I have NA values in my matrix and in my vector, maybe it's due to this?

Comment: A reproducible sample would get you the perfect solution. Can you update a toy data set using dput(head(data))?

Comment: Try `corrplot(cor(x, y, use = "complete.obs"))` also.

Comment: Well it works ! but the legend is crushed, Do you know how to enlarge cells and legend? thx

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574054/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-correlation-coefficient-in-corrplot