# How to have R corrplot title position correct?

Tags: r, title, correlation, figure, r-corrplot

Code and its output where title is wrongly positioned outside the window page:

```
library('corrplot')

#options(error=recover) # http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031603/54964
#debugger()
# load("last.dump.rda"); debugger(last.dump) # run if fail
options(error=function() dump.frames(to.file=TRUE))

# http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
        }
    }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat) 
  p.mat
}

M <- cor(mtcars)

p.mat <- cor.mtest(M)

title <- "ECG p-value significance"
col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot(M, method="color", col=col(200),  
     diag=FALSE, # tl.pos="d", 
         type="upper", order="hclust", 
     title=title, 
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         # Combine with significance
         p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.05, insig = "blank" 
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
         )
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5
Related ticket: [#72](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/72)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Code where `mar=c(0,0,1,0)` fixes the thing

```
library('corrplot')

# http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
        }
    }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat) 
  p.mat
}

M <- cor(mtcars)

p.mat <- cor.mtest(M)

title <- "ECG p-value significance"
col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot(M, method="color", col=col(200),  
     diag=FALSE, # tl.pos="d", 
         type="upper", order="hclust", 
     title=title, 
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         # Combine with significance
         p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.05, insig = "blank", 
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
     mar=c(0,0,1,0) # http://stackoverflow.com/a/14754408/54964
         )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of `mar=c(0,0,1,0)`?

Comment: plot margins (for sides), inherited from `par`: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html

Comment: Quote from the [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html): "A numerical vector of the form c(bottom, left, top, right) which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot. The default is c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1."

Comment: See github request: https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/72