# Corrplot in R not working

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to work out the correlation between these three labels using `corrplot`:

```
train.Item_ID   train.Price   train.Number_Of_Sales
30495           165.123          1
30375           68.666           5
30011           253.314          2
30864           223.122          1
30780           28.75            1
```

But somehow its not showing cross correlation between different labels.

```
corrplot(cor(newtrain),method = "number")
```

[image]

Basically it just shows 1,1,1 but no cross correlation and then size comes so smaller. Please suggest.

Comment: Is that all your data - if so , I cant reproduce. If not can you add the results of `dput(cor(newtrain))` to your question please.

Comment: When I look at your graph, I _DO_ see the cross correlations at the same size as the ones. They are just very pale because all the correlations are near zero.  Try adding `bg="lightgray"`  to your corrplot command.

Comment: @GSW yes it works fine now..thanks for pointing it out:)

Comment: @user20650..the problem as told by GSW was due to less correlation, now i understood the problem and no its just a sample of data, actual data is much larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a mess in your data. I got your data and it all works perfect:

```
library(corrplot)

d <- "train.Item_ID   train.Price   train.Number_Of_Sales
1 30495           165.123          1
2 30375           68.666           5
3 30011           253.314          2
4 30864           223.122          1
5 30780           28.75            1"

d <- read.table(text = d, header = T)

corrplot(cor(d), method = "number")
```

[image]

Comment: it was a color code issue, i have found it out..but thanks anyway:) also is there anyway to change the size of that plot?

Comment: You would need to play around with printing device and change width and height, see here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753344/corrplot-parameters-in-r